# Non-EU citizen living in the UK, any requirement for UK visa validity to visit Bulgaria?

Tags: visas, uk, bulgaria

I'm a non-EU citizen living in the UK. My UK visa is expiring at the end of September. Would it be possible for me to apply for a visa and visit Bulgaria in August? I know that for a Schengen visa, it's required that I have at least 3 months left on my UK visa after the end of the trip. Does a Bulgaria visitor visa have similar requirements?

Thanks for your help.

P.S: no problem with passport validity, my passport is valid until 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Bulgaria, while not yet part of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area), has a visa policy that is based on the Schengen acquis.

As an example, the [VFSGlobal](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html) Germany requirements don't specify that your UK visa has to be valid for three months after a Schengen area trip but, rather that, ***if*** your UK visa is not valid for three months afterwards, you would have to apply for the Schengen visa from your country of residence, e.g, your home country.